# How to add hard-coded literals to a query results on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(column1) AS Expr1
FROM Table1
```

I retrieve one row with one column.

How can I add a **second column** as string hard-codded?

I try to do like this with no success:

```
SELECT "Column2", COUNT(column1) AS Expr1
FROM Table1
```

The main purpose if fill a DataSet that has 2 columns and only one has to be taken from DataBase, the other can be set hard-coded as string.

Comment: If the question is about SQL Server, don't tag it with Oracle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT  'Column2' as ColumnName, COUNT(column1) AS Expr1
    FROM     Table1
```

Comment: Even `ColumnName` does not exists in my table?

Comment: This is not column name this is alias for newly added const column.

Comment: double quotes where the problem.

Comment: Double quotes were the problem for me as well. Thanks